# how to create an automatic traffic light sequence in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm relatively new to JavaScript and I'm attempting to create a traffic light sequence that runs automatically, the code I currently have only works on click, if anyone can help me make this automatic, that'd be great.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<img id="Change Lights" src="red.gif" width="36" height="98"> 

 <br><button onclick="nxt()" id="button">Change colour</button></br>

 <script>

var img = new Array("red.gif","redamber.gif","green.gif","yellow.gif");



var imgElement = document.getElementById("Change Lights");
var lights = 0;
var imgLen = img.length;

             function nxt()
        {
            if(lights < imgLen-1)
                {
                    lights++;
                }
            else{
                    lights=0;                
                }

                imgElement.src = img[lights];                    
        }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just helped someone with the exact same problem... Am i doing someone's homework here?? :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's going wrong with my timed Traffic Lights program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35903955/whats-going-wrong-with-my-timed-traffic-lights-program)

Comment: There are traffic lights with 4 colors? :O

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was posted yesterday, but I thought I'd chip in with an answer here.

**JavaScript**

```
var timeIndex = 0;
var lightIndex = 0;
var timer;
var trafficLight = document.getElementById('light');

var lights = [
    {
    duration: 5,
    color: 'red',
    image: 'red.gif'
  },
  {
    duration: 4,
    color: 'green',
    image: 'green.gif'
  },
  {
    duration: 1,
    color: 'yellow',
    image: 'yellow.gif'
  }
]

function advanceTrafficLightTimer() {
        timeIndex++;
    if(timeIndex == lights[lightIndex].duration) {
        timeIndex = 0;
        lightIndex = lightIndex < lights.length - 1 ? lightIndex = lightIndex + 1 : 0;
        trafficLight.src = lights[lightIndex].image;
        trafficLight.className = lights[lightIndex].color;
    }

}

timer = setInterval(advanceTrafficLightTimer,1000);
```

**CSS**

```
.red { border: 3px solid #f00; }
.green { border: 3px solid #0f0; }
.yellow { border: 3px solid #ff0; }
```

**HTML**

```
<img id="light" class="red" src="red.gif">
```

The JS works by updating the `timeIndex` every second, and checking a variable `lightIndex` against the available traffic light objects stored in the array `trafficLight`.  If the `timeIndex` has reached the duration of the current `trafficLight`, it will update the `lightIndex` to the next object in the array and change the image.

You can see it working here:  https://jsfiddle.net/igor_9000/a2w9g8qa/3/

This seems to be a homework problem (nothing wrong with posting questions about homework).  I've left out the `redamber` color, hopefully adding that in gives you a little bit of practice with the homework.

Hope that helps!